# Debugging asp.net with firefox and visual studio.net - very slow compared to IE

Tags: debugging, firefox, visual-studio-2005

Debugging asp.net websites/web projects in visual studio.net 2005 with Firefox is loads slower 
than using IE.

I've read something somewhere that there is a way of fixing this but i can't for the life of me find it again.

Does anyone know what i'm on about and can point me in the right direction please?

Cheers
John

### edit

sorry rob i haven't explained myself very well(again). I prefer Firefox for debugging (firebug etc)

hitting F5 when debugging with IE the browser launches really quickly and clicking around my web application is almost instant and when a breakpont is hit i get to my code straight away with no delays.

hitting F5 when debugging with FireFox the browser launches really slowly (ok i have plugins that slow FF loading) but clicking around my web application is really really slow and when a breakpoint is hit it takes ages to break into code.

i swear i've read something somewhere that there is a setting in Firefox (about:config maybe?) that when changed to some magic setting sorts all this out.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

bingo. found the [article](http://dotnetslackers.com/ASP_NET/re-122146_Speeding_Up_FireFox_When_Using_the_ASP_NET_Development_Server_from_Localhost.aspx) i read before.

i just changed my network.dns.ipv4OnlyDomains property in about:config to localhost. restarted firefox and now firefox performs the same as IE when debugging asp.net with visual studio (2005).

hope this helps anyone else that has the same problem.

Comment: You can also manually change localhost in the browser address bar to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 13):

"Alternative solution". Do the following in Firefox

1. about:config in the address bar
2. set network.dns.disableIPv6 to true.

Comment: Worked for me. IMHO this is actually a nicer solution, since IPv6 isn't really used yet (?)

Comment: This worked a treat for me. Those dns lookups were horrendous when debugging against cassini

Comment: Attention: Quote from above article:

"...many pages around the Web suggested that you set the nework.dns.disableIPv6 property to true, but this would disable IPv6 support for all sites visited by the browser (at least according to the Wiki documentation)"

Answer (score 0):

Are you serious? One of the main reasons I stick to Firefox is because its so much nicer to develop with..

The live source update is awesome (view source > change code > rebuild > F5 in source)...

What is actually "slow".. I mean, the some browsers tend to be slower at rendering, but I dont see how it affects your debug time? As soon as the request is made, and your breakpoint is hit in the code, it stops?

Answer (score 0):

For quick debugging try this..

Add Debugger.Break() into your code at an appropriate place.

Browse to the page in firefox (via localhost) if on local dev machine? and the Visual Studio Just in Time debugger should pop up.. select the currently open instance of Visual Studio and you can step into the code where every you want without having to start from the beginning or jumping to cursor.

-- Lee