# Debugging asp.net with chrome and visual studio.net - very slow compared to IE

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, google-chrome

This Question describes Firefox responding much slower than IE for debugging ASP.NET apps with visual studio:

[Debugging asp.net with firefox and visual studio.net - very slow compared to IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24959/debugging-asp-net-with-firefox-and-visual-studio-net-very-slow-compared-to-ie)

I am having the exact same problem with Chrome.  Pages load very fast in IE, but there is about a 5 second lag loading every page in Chrome.

The suggestions in the question I linked don't work on Chrome, and I can't find any articles on the web tackling this problem for Chrome.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue on Chrome?  Thank you.

Comment: Same with firefox. Waiting for the answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there is no way to disable IPv6 within Chrome, so you will have to do it in the operating system, e.g. by modifying the hosts file as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795451/asp-net-mvc-on-cassini-how-can-i-force-the-content-directory-to-return-304s-in/3014211#3014211).