# VS2008 on Windows 8 stepping through when debugging a web-app takes a long time

Tags: asp.net, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2008

When I try to step through a web-app via F10 key in VS2008 running on Windows 8 Pro it takes about 3 seconds for each step through to complete.

On windows XP and windows 7 running VS2008 debugging the same project that doesn't happen.

If anyone has a idea of why this would be happening on Windows 8 only, please do share.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm using the Chrome Browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed a lot of the watch variables from the Watch 1 window during debugging and stepping through is now basically happening in real time with no delay.

Strange how this doesn't need to be done on Windows 7 or XP.

I guess it is another notch on the list of Windows 8 quirks.

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you using? This used to be an issue with FireFox and Ipv6. If you are using FireFox please try these steps :

1. Open FireFox browser.
2. Type 'about:config' in the address bar (without the single quotes).
3. Type this in the Search bar that appears : Ipv6
4. You should see the 'network.dns.disableIPv6' property and click on
   Toggle. Restart FireFox browser.
5. Debug again and see if the debugging is now faster.

Comment: From Chrome browser please [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260399/debugging-asp-net-with-chrome-and-visual-studio-net-very-slow-compared-to-ie) post.

Comment: Also, the same is happening in IE. I only have IE 10 installed on this machine aside from Chrome.

Comment: If I am not wrong ASP.NET starts a local instance of the server that appears as a icon in the windows task bar. Right click it and shutdown the server instance. Perform a clean build of the web app and launch it again. Then wait a few minutes, stop debugging and launch again. I have asked to do this twice because the first time you run the web page it will compile and loading will be slower than subsequent loads of the page. If this does not work post the page code in your original query.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've done everything you've suggested and I'm sure it did help. But my solution below is what really did it. The solution came out of desperation, I was basically trying 'everything under the sun'.